# What does 'M10 x 1.00' mean when referring to fuel injectors?

Tags: vw, fuel-system, fuel-injection, fuel-line

I need to replace some fuel lines (from the injector control to the injector) on my 93 VW Cabriolet. The site that sells the lines has 2 options for the 'Injector Size': M10 x 1.00 or M12 x 1.5.

I'm not sure what either of these mean or how I can check to see which one my injectors are.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are [metric screw dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_metric_screw_thread). M10 means a 10 millimeter outer diameter for the bolt or whatever piece it is; M12 means 12 millimeters. The part after the 'x' is the pitch -- how many mm a thread is wide.

To figure out which you have, you can measure the existing part with [calipers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipers#Vernier_caliper) and a [thread gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pitch_gauge). You might also try calling your local VW dealer with your VIN handy; actually I'm surprised that the website you're purchasing from doesn't tell you which you need based on the VIN. You might look into that a bit more, or try another site or two.